# Get paypal user information after sale creation

Tags: paypal

I am integrating Paypal into a shopping cart and I want to get the user's shipping information after creating a payment.  I know there was a method to do so using the old api, but it seems that the api has changed when developer.paypal.com was launched.  I do not see what url I need to use in order to get extended payer information.

So far, I am sending the user to paypal for creation and when the user comes back, I have a payer id and token.  From previous call, I have an execution link, but no details link.  Do I need to force the user to enter shipping information before reaching out to paypal?  If that is the case, it just seems confusing that Paypal shows shipping information from their system and not mine.

How do I get a payer's shipping details from paypal once they have approved an amount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most merchants use PayPal Instant Payment Notification (IPN) to receive payment details including the shipping address. This allows you to receive real time notifications from PayPal rather than pinging us once you believe a payment is made. Below is a simple PHP script that will take the IPN and validate it to ensure it wasn't a spoof attempt. Once validated you can update your database, send an email or whatever task is needed once you know payment has been made.

```
// Validate with curl
  $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)  
  {  
       $value =  urlencode(stripslashes($value));  
       $req .=  "&" . $key . "=" . $value;  
  }

  $curl_result=$curl_err='';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'www.paypal.com');//Change URL to sandbox.paypal.com if testing in our developer environment
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",  "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  $curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
  $curl_err = curl_error($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  //Set validation flag
  if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED")!==false)
       $valid  = true;
  else
       $valid  = false;
```

This method is much more reliable than Payment Data Transfer (PDT) as it doesn't rely on the consumer to return to your site for payment to be made.

Comment: I guess I needed to add that I require shipping address before the final execution so I can determine shipping price.  It seems like waiting for the IPN would be too late in the process.

Comment: If you're using Express Checkout then Callback API would be great to use. Once the customer is directed to PayPal and provides a shipping address we'll ping your server with the shipping address, amount and item details then you'll reply with the shipping options and amounts. More information can be found at https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/callback-api-operation-nvp

Comment: I think that will work.  I think the main problem is that the new developer site really downplays the other apis which still seem necessary and I couldn't find any documentation on the differences between them all and when to use what.  Hope the paypal team gets that whole mess cleaned up.